# Calling several tex files with a loop?

Tags: loops

I have 160 tex files named "regj.tex" for j=1,...,160. Each file contains a table. These tex files do not contain the preamble/begin{document}/end{document}. For example reg1.tex is

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{Reg1}
\begin{tabular}{l*{9}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1.1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1.2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1.3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2.1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2.2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2.3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3.1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3.2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3.3)}\\
\hline
A&      0.0599&       0.172&       0.110&       0.200&       0.574&       0.368&       640.2&      1836.0&      1177.8\\
            &         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)\\
[1em]
B&      -3.181&      -2.978&      -2.967&      -0.875&      -0.197&      -0.160&     -2929.9&      -762.1&      -641.9\\
            &         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)\\
[1em]
C&      -13.09&      -15.68&      -15.28&       15.56&       6.904&       8.245&     44234.8&     16538.5&     20827.6\\
            &         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)\\
[1em]
D&   -259451.5&   -242691.5&   -241750.9&    -70803.4&    -14782.8&    -11638.9&-238755093.5& -59586716.2& -49531616.2\\
            &         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)\\
[1em]
E&     69993.2&     65360.3&     65152.5&     20567.4&      5081.7&      4387.2&  70028268.8&  20501094.0&  18279814.0\\
            &         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)&         (.)\\
\hline
Number of observations:&          30&          30&          30&          30&          30&          30&          30&          30&          30\\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{10}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I would like to create an executable tex file reg0.tex calling all the tables with a loop. How can I do it?

Comment: Just use the `pgffor` package, and its `\foreach` feature. Note also the build in ... Effect

Answer (score 13):

There are numerous ways to do this, but the simplest given what you've described is to use the `pgffor` package which provides a simple syntax for such loops:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
% next code just generates some files to mimic yours
\begin{filecontents}{test-table-1.tex}
\begin{table}[htpb]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
A & B & C\\
A & B & C
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test-table-2.tex}
\begin{table}[htpb]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
D & E & F\\
D & E & F
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test-table-3.tex}
\begin{table}[htpb]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
G & H & I\\
G & E & F
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{filecontents}
%end of files
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {1,...,3}{
\input{test-table-\x}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 6):

Here's an approach based on the LaTeX 3 syntax made available by `expl3`. I modified the table a bit to get it to fit. Otherwise, I just duplicated your example to 3 different files with 3 different captions.

Obviously, `geometry` is optional. I just used it to make things fit for demonstration purposes.

The preamble defines a new command with the following syntax

```
\inputloop[<optional prefix>]{<number of files>}
```

If no optional prefix is given, `reg` is used as the default.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse,geometry}
\geometry{scale=.9}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\inputloop { O { reg } m }
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #2 }
   {
    \input { #1 ##1 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
  \small
  \inputloop{3}
\end{document}
```

[image: looping input]

Comment: I took the liberty of streamlining a bit your code. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I was about to do it! I just have to understand it before I use it....

Comment: Slicker, isn't it? `:-)`

Comment: @egreg Yes, of course. Thank you :). How do I know when I need a `\begin_group: ... \end_group:`. Is it just when I'd need a group? I mean, I saw lots of examples using it where I didn't think people would have used groups - at least, it wasn't obvious why - so I started to think there was something different here.

Comment: In the old code there was no need for groups. There would be if you nested calls using the same variable. It's no different from standard TeX programming.

Comment: Thanks. The 'no different...' is the bit I wanted. I figured if they weren't necessary here, they weren't necessary with my scenic route either. I think I've just somehow come to associate them with this syntax for some reason.

Comment: @egreg If you didn't need to use the value but only to increment it to keep count, would you still use this or is there something better? Using this seems easier than what I had, but I don't actually need to make use of the value. Maybe that doesn't matter?

Comment: Probably `\prg_replicate:nn` is what you need.

Comment: @egreg Thank you! Yes, that indeed works well. It means an additional step first to manipulate the counter, but it is still simpler, I think. I would not have thought of looking elsewhere in the manual than stuff with `int` in it somewhere.